# Turning an Array into a Data Frame

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe, knitr

I would like to put my summary statistics into a table using the kable function, but I cannot because it comes up as an array.

````
```{r setup options, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 8, fig.height = 5, echo = TRUE)
library(mosaic)
library(knitr)
```

```{r}
sum = summary(SwimRecords$time)    # generic data set included with mosaic package
kable(sum)    # I want this to be printed into a table
```
````

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so easily with the `broom` package which is built to "tidy" these stats-related objects:

```
#install.packages(broom)
broom::tidy(sum)
```

Comment: Awesome, this is a perfect, simple solution. Thank you!